# PHP retrieving user settings

Tags: php, mysql

I was hoping someone could clarify a question I had with this technique from post: [User Setting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125166/best-way-of-storing-user-settings-in-mysql)

1. If I am using PHP PDO and MySQL is it necessary to use the process that utilize the columns:

> type BOOL
>   value_int INT NULL
>   value_str VARCHAR NUL

and not just a varchar column to store any value (numeric or string) without a "type" column?

Thanks for the help

Edit for Clarification:
Is there any disadvantage to build tables as below than above post link.

> TABLE Users:
>   id INT AI
>   name VARCHAR
>   ...
>
> TABLE User_Settings
>   user_id INT PK,FK
>   name VARCHAR PK
>   value
>   VARCHAR NULL

Comment: question is unclear

Comment: Use whatever is most suitable.

Comment: np, I will do that. I was just trying to see the advantage of storing separately a string(varchar) and int type like they did originally vs storing  value (numbers or characters) in a varchar. Perhaps for reporting output.